# Intent object on onActivityreslut goes null on Image capture android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-image-capture

I am trying to set a image as profile picture on image view after capture using camera. image capturing is working fine and image is stored in device memory. But on onActivityResult code intent object goes null.

Here is the code for call camera action

```
 Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(Utilities.getOutputMediaFile());
                    camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(camera, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA);
```

which is calling from a dialoge and in Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Constants.LOGIN_REQUEST) {
            if (AppSettings.getInstance(HomeScreen.this).getBooleanValue(AppKeys.LOGIN_STATUS)) {changeFragment(new Fragment_Account());
            }
        } else {
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

In fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ProfilePicUri = (Uri) data.getExtras().get(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                Log.d("ImageUri", "onActivityResult: " + ProfilePicUri);
                performCrop();
            } else if (requestCode == Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_GALLERY) {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    ProfilePicUri = data.getData();
                    performCrop();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == Constants.IMAGE_CROP) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap newProfilePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    if (newProfilePic != null) {
                        customer.setProfilePic(Utilities.encodeTobase64(newProfilePic));
                        profilePic.setImageBitmap(newProfilePic);
                        Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) profilePic.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        String imageUrls = Utilities.encodeTobase64(image);
                        String imageString = image.toString();
                        Log.d("imageUrl : ", imageUrls);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in activity and fragment `data` came as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But on onActivityResult code intent object goes null.

It is supposed to be `null`. You know where the image should be located: it is where you specified in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Look there for the image.

Also note that `Uri.fromFile()` will not work for you on Android 7.0+, once your `targetSdkVersion` climbs to 24 or higher. Please switch to using `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Camera/FileProvider) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android) illustrates how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Remove the line where you set the path to save your file unless you
>   need to set your custom path to save your file.

Once an URI is set by

```
Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
```

the resulting intent will be null and it's designed to perform like that.

onActivityResult,

```
intent.getData()
```

will give you the URI of the captured image.

Comment: "will give you the URI of the captured image" -- no, it will not. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a result, and many camera apps will not return a result.

Comment: so what's the documented solution for that?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49448932/115145). You specified where the image should be via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`; you should not need that value sent back to you. Now, there are *many* buggy camera apps, so if the image is not at the location identified by `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, checking to see if there is an `Intent` and `Uri` in `onActivityResult()` is something to try as a fallback option.